# UIAlertController throws NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to get an alert to pop up with UIAlertController, but I keep getting this error:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <States: 0x17557b90>.'`

```
if([InAppPurchaseVerifier hasSubscription]){

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self.fullList objectAtIndex:row]];

    NSString *state = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [myDict objectForKey:@"0"]];
    NSString *stateDetails = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [myDict objectForKey:@"1"]];

    OfficeInfo *anotherViewController = [[OfficeInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"OfficeInfo" bundle:nil];
    anotherViewController.stateName = state;
    anotherViewController.stateDetails = stateDetails;

    [state release];
    [stateDetails release];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
    [anotherViewController release];
}else{
    UIAlertController* alert = [[UIAlertController init] alertControllerWithTitle:@"Subscription Needed" message:@"You need to subscribe in order to access that. If you already have a subscription you may need to restore it" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]; // Error throws here
}
```

Comment: `UIAlertController` is only available in iOS 8.  Are you, perhaps, trying to run it on an earlier version of the OS?

Comment: Yeah, that must be it. I'm testing it out on our iOS 7 device... So the old alert thing is depreciated in 8, but we'll have to use it for a while. Good to know!

Comment: Yeah, you have do a check and branch.  It's lame.  You can probably just write a wrapper.

Comment: I have this happening now in 9.2.1, on my device, however it isn't crashing on the simulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UIAlertController` is only available in iOS 8.  For previous versions, you must check and fallback to the old code path, continue to use the deprecated API, or write a happy little wrapper object.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Even though it's depreciated, any problem with just using the old UIAlertView for iOS 7 and 8?

Comment: It will still work.  "Any problem" sort of depends on your personal tolerance for risk.  Apple may reject you for using deprecated APIs at some point (low-risk of this in my experience).  Apple may remove it in an SDK update and then you must change your code (medium-risk, depends on your shipping schedule).  So, really, just look inside yourself and see what answer flows from within.